# I want to make the code diagram below

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm); % Soleil
\draw (6,0) circle (0.5cm); % Terre
\draw (8,0) circle (0.2cm); % Lune
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (6,0); % Distance Terre-Soleil
\draw[dashed] (6,0) -- (8,0); % Distance Terre-Lune
\node at (3,0.3) {$D$}; % Distance Terre-Soleil
\node at (7,0.3) {$d$}; % Distance Terre-Lune
\node at (-0.5,-2.5) {Soleil};
\node at (6,-1) {Terre};
\node at (8,-0.5) {Lune};
\draw[red] (8,0) arc (90:270:0.2cm); % Surface de la Lune exposée au Soleil
\node[red] at (8,-1) {$S_L$}; % Surface de la Lune exposée au Soleil
\draw[blue] (2,0) arc (90:270:2cm); % Surface de la sphère imaginaire
\node[blue] at (2,-3) {$S_S$}; % Surface de la sphère imaginaire
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! You've already done it, didn't you? What's the question? Please note that the language here is English.

Comment: I think the problem is that an `arc`does not use the last coordinate as its center but actually starts there. Try `\draw[red] (8,0.2cm) arc (90:270:0.2cm);` instead or, better yet, use the preferred syntax: `\draw[red] (8,0.2cm) arc[start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=0.2cm];`

Comment: By the way, you can omit `cm`, as this is the default unit in `tikzpicture`s anyways.

Comment: Welcome. // And your question is ... ?

Comment: Egreg je le veut sous forme de schéma et non sous forme codé

Comment: Il serait peut-être plus facile de comprendre quel est ton objectif si tu le demandais en anglais. Seule une petite partie des utilisateurs ici parle français. Mais même avec des connaissances linguistiques, il est difficile de comprendre quel est ton objectif. Je n'ai aucune idée de ce que signifie "forme de schéma". Peux-tu ajouter une image montrant à quoi devrait ressembler le résultat ? Merci !

Comment: @Pinou, so you ask what to do to compile it? (translate.google.com: alors vous demandez quoi faire pour le compiler ?)

Answer (score 2):

It is not fully clear to me what you want to achieve, but I think the problem you encounter is that you think an `arc` uses the last coordinate given as its center (like a `circle` does), but in fact, the last coordinate is where the arc actually starts.

I think what you want to draw is something like the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (S) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (T) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (L) at (8,0);
    
    \draw (S) +(0,2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, radius=2] % Soleil
        node[below] {Soleil};
    \draw (T) circle[radius=.5] % Terre
        +(0,-0.5) node[below] {Terre}; 
    \draw (L) +(0,.2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, radius=.2] % Lune
        node[below] {Lune};
    
    \draw[dashed] (S) -- (T) % Distance Terre-Soleil
        node[midway, above] {$D$};
    \draw[dashed] (T) -- (L) % Distance Terre-Lune
        node[midway, above] {$d$};
    
    \draw[red] (L) +(0,.2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=.2] % Surface de la Lune exposée au Soleil
        node[at start, above] {$S_L$};
    \draw[blue] (S) +(0,2) arc[start angle=90, end angle=270, radius=2] % Surface de la sphère imaginaire 
        node[at start, above] {$S_S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]